# Is it possible to convert []byte to os.File and vise versa in-memory or anyhow export/import file as os.File to/from database?

Tags: file, go

I'm writing a program on MacOS, that has to make user-space-filesystem via FUSE and [gofuse](https://github.com/hanwen/go-fuse). The idea is to store all files inside a database (SQLITE for example) and implement FUSE-methods to access those files from FUSE-mountpoint. For this to work I have to efficiently store my files as os.File or have some methods to convert []byte to os.File struct, because I have to work with os.File objects, while implementing Write and Read functions inside FUSE.

Is there any way to convert []byte to os.File in-memory, without making any additional files on hard drive?

Comment: Take a look at [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) in the standard library, it does basically this (not as an `os.File`, that's impossible, but it exposes a `[]byte` as an `io.ReadWriter`).

Comment: @Adrian, thank you, i'll take a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do it because `os.File` holds a file descriptor, this descriptor is a number managed by operating system. It is valid while the file is open, when it gets closed, it is unusable.